# ZXingTestActivity - barcode scanner - No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }

Tags: android-emulator

I've been trying to build an application that uses **barcode scanner**, and I've decided to try out the example found in the **ZXing-2.0.zip** ,so I went in my eclipse and imported the **androidtest** application as an existing android application into my workspace, the code compiles ok with no errors.

Now after running the app on my AVD all the buttons appear right as it should be

When clicking **scan product** button it gives me this stack in the LogCat and the application needs to close:

```
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.google.zxing.client.androidtest.ZXingTestActivity$3.onClick(ZXingTestActivity.java:153)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-09 13:10:47.542: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is rather weird because because the activity he's talking about should be ZXingTestActivity

So what am I missing here ? Thank you!!

Answer (score 19):

Just Add this Code into your manifest file, with in the Application tag.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now add permission if not already added on the top of file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: why have you duplicated OP's answer? this is exactly what he posted as a solution long time ago, but with no description of what's going on.

Comment: i did not duplicate anyone's answer. i faced this problem and there was nothing here to help.

Comment: I'll let future visitors to decide for themselves - code you've pasted is exactly the same as the code on the page which OPs answer (older by about 8 months) points to via a link. I also doubt that his answer can be described as "nothing here to help".

Comment: thanks buddy its works great as i get the same error.keep it up :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. you can look this page"http://pastebin.com/J5EV72Cu".

 **Error coding**

```
String packageString = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage(packageString);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

**Solve coding**

```
String packageString = "com.yourapplication.packagename";
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage(packageString);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

Comment: Instead of giving pastebin link, include that code in your answer. Otherwise it might be closed with link-only answer reason.

Comment: This pastebin file is very confused. And the solution doesn't work. The _resultCode_ still diferent then _RESULT_OK_ in  _onActivityResult_

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem you can find the solution [here](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/)

What you need to do is add the mentioned piece to the manifest file. Good luck!!

Comment: Link not active!!